# Adding input value from php in angular function

Tags: php, angularjs, scope

I have an input with a value setted by php variable:
    `<input id="name" type="text"  value="<?php if(isset($cib)){echo $cib;}?">`. 
I want use this value to set all the object of angularjs function as showed in the following code:

```
`angular.forEach($scope.food, function(obj){
obj["price"] = 500;
obj["detail"] = variable_x;
obj["count"] = 1;
obj["id"] = 1;
});`
```

If I assign tue value the "variable_X" as I showed in the following codes, it doesn't work. I tried:

```
var variable_X=<?php if(isset($cib)){echo $cib;}  ?>
```

or

```
`var variable_X=document.getElementById("name");'
```

or using ng-model.

Can I obtain the value of this variable in another way?

Answer (score 0):

```
var variable_X=<?php if(isset($cib)){echo $cib;}  ?>
```

that should work fine, but it will throw an error if `$cib` is not set right?

the statement will become this to the browser if `$cib` is undefined...

```
var variable_X= ;
```

which fails...

need to set variable to something when it fails..

```
var variable_X=<?php isset($cib) ? $cib : 'false'  ?>;
```

then in angular check for FALSE value of $cib and do stuff

Answer (score 0):

I use `ng-init` for assigning initial values when rendering html:

```
<div ng-controller="..." ng-init="cib = '<?php if(isset($cib)){echo $cib;}?>'">
```

Then you can use `cib` both in template and in controller's code:

```
obj["detail"] = $scope.cib
```

(note: reading from $scope)